# Connecting to WebService via HTTPS throws SCL Profile Allocation error

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-ws, sybase, easerver

I'm trying to use Jax-WS generated classes (created using wsimport) to 
call a webservice over an HTTPS connection from within a Java 
component in the application server **Sybase EAServer 5.3**.  I get an exception in the EAServer log with 
the following as its underlying cause (I have removed the URL of the 
webservice).

```
2009-11-15 18:39:58,338: ALL [Thread-19] - Caused by: 
java.io.IOException: https://www.<my website url>.com:443: SCL profile 
allocation
2009-11-15 18:39:58,338: ALL [Thread-19] -  at 
com.sybase.jaguar.net.HttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnection.java:521)
2009-11-15 18:39:58,338: ALL [Thread-19] -  at 
java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
2009-11-15 18:39:58,338: ALL [Thread-19] -  at 
com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:804)
2009-11-15 18:39:58,338: ALL [Thread-19] -  at 
com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:262)
2009-11-15 18:39:58,338: ALL [Thread-19] -  at 
com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:129)
2009-11-15 18:39:58,338: ALL [Thread-19] -  ... 18 more
```

I am pretty sure this is because I need to set up EAServer to accept 
the SSL certificate of this website.  The connection code itself is 
all generated by Jax-WS so I am not actually creating the connection 
myself.  It takes place in the generated classes.

Any ideas how to properly configure EAServer so that 
**com.sybase.jaguar.net.HttpsURLConnection.getInputStream** will 
successfully create an HTTPS connection to the endpoint of the 
webservice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with Sybase support to get this one resolved.  It involved updating EAServer to use the Sun security provider instead of the Sybase one.  Within the 
Jaguar.props we updated the JVM options to be:

```
com.sybase.jaguar.server.jvm.options=-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=sun.security.provider.Sun|com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl
```

This lets it use the Sun security provider and I stopped getting the 
`SCL profile allocation` message.

After doing this I started getting NullPointerExceptions from the 
JAX-WS classes in the log (which I confirmed was related to 
configuring JAX-WS for use within EAServer, nothing to do with the SSL 
Webservice).

I had to add my generated webservice stubs jar (that I created using 
wsimport) to the Jaguar.props property 
`com.sybase.jaguar.server.java.classes`

I also added this generated stubs jar and the JAX-WS runtime libraries 
to the 2 Jaguar.props properties 
`com.sybase.jaguar.server.jvm.bootclasspath.jars` and 
`com.sybase.jaguar.server.jvm.classpath.jars`

Then I copied the JAX-WS runtime libraries and my generated webservice 
stubs jar to the `C:\Sybase\EAServer\java\lib` directory and everything 
started working like a champ.